# Plotly histogram labels

Tags: plotly

Any idea how I could write direct labels on my plotly histograms ? I'll export them so I need to write down the labels.

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[
            go.Histogram(name='Green', x=df['ACTION'], y=df['1'],text=df['1'],histfunc='sum'),
            go.Histogram(name='orange', x=df['ACTION'], y=df['2'],text="test",histfunc='avg'),
            go.Histogram(name='blue', x=df['ACTION'], y=df['3'],text="test",histfunc='avg')
        ])
```

texposition work for bars, but not for histogram. And I need the avg fuction of histogram.

```
Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Histogram: 'textposition'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently looking for the text attribute on histogram but it seems that it is not implemented, I think if text is not implemented textposition wont be either